# Why is Google still not indexing my !# webpage?

Tags: search-engine-indexing

Our website is not getting indexing on google search engine. some webpages are indexing and some pages are not indexing. how can i resolve this problem. please help us.

Comment: i suppose the question is about indexation of ajax application website. There is great guide for such issues with ajax application websites: http://ajax.rswebanalytics.com/

Answer (score 0):

Why this message is coming on your website whenever I clicked on a page "Sorry, you are unable to Register at the movement, please try after some time". I believe crawler is finding difficulties to crawl your website pages

Answer (score 0):

You can ask Google to crawl your website manually.

Here: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?hl=en

OR

Recommended:

1. Signup for Google Webmasters tools at https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en
2. Add and verify your website
3. Click on Crawl > Fetch as Google
4. Input URL of your webpages you want to index and them both as Desktop and Mobile: Smartphone - Current
5. Crawl only this URL or All links on the page (as your preference) and submit.

> Note: Google adds new sites to our index, and updates existing ones,
>   every time we crawl the web. If you have a new URL, tell us about it
>   here. We don't add all submitted URLs to our index, and we can't make
>   predictions or guarantees about when or if submitted URLs will appear
>   in our index.